# If statment to echo an image if var=EUR doesnt work

Tags: php

This code added currency switcher to a menu,

But unfortunately I don't have access to MySQL database so I can't add image "flag" to each currency, then execute them

So I tried to use if statement.

This is my code:

```
$currency_switcher_enable = houzez_option('currency_switcher_enable');
$is_multi_currency = houzez_option('multi_currency');

if( $currency_switcher_enable != 0 && $is_multi_currency != 1 ) {
    if (class_exists('FCC_Rates')) {

        $supported_currencies = houzez_get_list_of_supported_currencies();

        if (0 < count($supported_currencies)) {

            $current_currency = houzez_get_wpc_current_currency();

            echo '<li class="btn-price-lang btn-price">';
            
            echo '<form id="houzez-currency-switcher-form" method="post" action="#" class="open">';
            echo '<button id="houzez-selected-currency" class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><span>' . $current_currency . '</span> <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></button>';
            echo '<ul id="houzez-currency-switcher-list" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown" style="display:none;">';
            foreach ($supported_currencies as $currency_code) {
                echo '<li data-currency-code="' . $currency_code . '">' . $currency_code . '</li>';
                if (data-currency-code='EUR') {
                    echo '<img src="images/euro-flag.png"';
                    if (data-currency-code='TR') {
                    echo '<img src="images/turkish-flag.png"';
                }
            }
            echo '</ul>';

            echo '<input type="hidden" id="houzez-switch-to-currency" name="houzez_switch_to_currency" value="' . $current_currency . '" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" id="currency_switch_security" name="nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce('houzez_currency_converter_nonce') . '"/>';

            echo '</form>';
            echo '</li>';

        }
    }
}
?>
```

**But it doesn't work? What I'm doing wrong?**

This is the original code:

```
$currency_switcher_enable = houzez_option('currency_switcher_enable');
$is_multi_currency = houzez_option('multi_currency');

if( $currency_switcher_enable != 0 && $is_multi_currency != 1 ) {
    if (class_exists('FCC_Rates')) {

        $supported_currencies = houzez_get_list_of_supported_currencies();

        if (0 < count($supported_currencies)) {

            $current_currency = houzez_get_wpc_current_currency();

            echo '<li class="btn-price-lang btn-price">';
            echo '<form id="houzez-currency-switcher-form" method="post" action="#" class="open">';
            echo '<button id="houzez-selected-currency" class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><span>' . $current_currency . '</span> <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></button>';
            echo '<ul id="houzez-currency-switcher-list" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown" style="display:none;">';
            foreach ($supported_currencies as $currency_code) {
                echo '<li data-currency-code="' . $currency_code . '">' . $currency_code . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';

            echo '<input type="hidden" id="houzez-switch-to-currency" name="houzez_switch_to_currency" value="' . $current_currency . '" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" id="currency_switch_security" name="nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce('houzez_currency_converter_nonce') . '"/>';

            echo '</form>';
            echo '</li>';

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (data-currency-code='EUR') {`, `if (data-currency-code='TR') {`: `=` is assigning, `==` does comparison (Does that code even work in PHP?)

Comment: @kerbh0lz, that should be the problem, PHP string comparison works the same as most programming languages work

Comment: And you probably want to use `$currency_code` instead of `data-currency-code` in those comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many fails here:

1. The first is as @kerbh0lz mentioned, the "=" and "==" is not the same purpose. here yours is wrong.
2. Second your second currency If is in the 1st Currency If so it wont ever pass by.
3. Third you are comparing a string without quote or a var without $ before `data-currency-code` so instead you should use `$currency_code`

Try this:

```
foreach ($supported_currencies as $currency_code) {
                echo '<li data-currency-code="' . $currency_code . '">' . $currency_code . '</li>';
                if ($currency_code =='EUR')
                    echo '<img src="images/euro-flag.png"';
                elseif ($currency_code == 'TR')
                    echo '<img src="images/turkish-flag.png"';
               
            }
```